# Is Alfresco 5 compatible with JDK 1.5?

Tags: alfresco

I am using Alfresco 5 with JDK 1.5. Below are the jars i am using

1. alfresco-opencmis-extension-0.3
2. alfresco-web-service-client
3. chemistry-opencmis-client-api-0.10.0
4. chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings-0.9.0
5. chemistry-opencmis-client-impl-0.10.0
6. chemistry-opencmis-commons-api-0.10.0
7. chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl-0.10.0

I have configured all the parameters and I'm getting the error below while getting the repository -- (`repositories = factory.getRepositories(parameter)`)

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConnectionException: Unexpected document! Received: HTML document
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:491)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.csdcsystems.amanda.common.CsdcServletFilter.doFilter(CsdcServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConnectionException: Unexpected document! Received: HTML document
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.parse(AbstractAtomPubService.java:584)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.getRepositoriesInternal(AbstractAtomPubService.java:765)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfos(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:62)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfos(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at com.csdcsystems.amanda.edms.EDMSAdaptor_Alfresco.initialize(EDMSAdaptor_Alfresco.java:127)
    at com.csdcsystems.amanda.edms.EDMSAdaptorFactory.getAdaptor(EDMSAdaptorFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.jsp.english.FolderDocumentDetail_005fSend_jsp._jspService(FolderDocumentDetail_005fSend_jsp.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    ... 18 more
```

Please confirm that the jars I used are correct or not. Let me know if anything needs to be added.

Thanks,
Thanga

Comment: also, alfresco depends on maven, and maven, says google, depends on java 1.7+

Comment: Please show more of your code and describe a little more the environment you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco (both Enterprise and community) support JDK 7 U60 X64 for version 5.0 and JDK 7 U67 X64, JDK 8 U25 X64 for version 5.0.1, as you can find in the [Alfresco supported platforms document](https://www.alfresco.com/services/subscription/supported-platforms),version 5.0.x in the JDK section.

Note that JDK means Oracle JDK.

About the exception you get, it seems that a wrong response type is returned to your call. As stated [here](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/error-connecting-alfresco-cmis-unexpected-document-received) it may be a matter of CMIS implementation version. Alfresco 5.0 uses the CMIS 1.1 implementation.

I would suggest you to take a look to this [Alfresco CMIS wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS) in order to get more information, and especially to the CMIS toolkits like Apache Chemistry in order to download a newer version.

Comment: I don't think it will work properly, since they certify a correct behavior if used with JDK version 1.7+. Why do you have to stick to JDK 1.5 version?

Comment: My application is compatible with JDK1.5 only.

Comment: The above exception is resolved by changing the webservice URL. Now i am getting below new exception.